# Cannot catch exception in spring batch's ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm writing a Spring Batch process to migrate a dataset from one system into another. In this case this is as simple as using a `RowMapper` implementation to build the object from a query before handing off to the `ItemWriter`. The `ItemWriter` calls the `save` method on my DAO (defined as an interface and handled by spring data)

The issue is this: I have a unique constraint on the MyItem table, and therefore saving a duplicated record will result in a `DataIntegrityViolationException`. I have tried catching this within the `ItemWriter` to allow me to log that a record was not imported, however during execution it never enters this catch statement. I have attempted catching `Exception` AND `Throwable` to no avail too.

From what I've noticed, there is a `@Transactional` annotation on the 'save' method of my DAO where I would expect the commit and flush to occur. Does Spring Batch alter this transaction in any way? Such that the `@Transactional` annotation applies to the 'write' method of the `ItemWriter`?

Can I even catch the exception in this class?

I've provided code snippets below, if you need further information - please let me know.

Many thanks for any help you can provide

**ItemWriter**

```
@Component
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyItem> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyItemWriter.class);

    @Resource
    private MyItemDao myItemDao;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyItem> myItems) throws Exception {
        for (MyItem myItem : myItems) {
            try {
                myItemDao.save(myItem);
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                LOG.warn("Failed to import MyItem: {}: {} ", myItem.getId(), ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
public interface MyItemDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyItem, Integer> {
    [Custom methods omitted]
}
```

**Spring Batch configuration**

```
<batch:job id="myImportJob" restartable="true" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="myImportStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader" writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="50" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: There is a single transaction going on for all items in your chunk it commits everything. The save method just participates in this transactions, which will commit each 50 records and not single records. So catching the exception isn't going to be possible. Add an `ItemProcessor` into the mix which checks if the record needs to be written or should be discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple points here:

1. Remove the `@Transactional` annotation on your DAO.  `@Transactional` and Spring Batch typically don't play nice.  Spring Batch manages the transactions as part of the framework's functionality and attempting to manipulate that functionality can cause unexpected side effects.
2. As M. Deinum points out, your `ItemWriter` and therefore your DAO is participating in a transaction that Spring Batch is managing.  Because of this, you won't get that exception until the transaction commits.

With the above considerations in place, you have two options:

1. You can configure skip logic to skip records that throw that exception.  If you need to log the item, you can add a `SkipListener` to the mix so that you can log the item that caused the exception.  However, there is a performance penalty to be paid with this approach since throwing the exception will result in the transaction being rolled back and replayed one item at a time.
2. You can filter the items via an `ItemProcessor`.  This saves the performance hit for skip logic.

You can read more about Spring Batch's skip logic in section 5.1.5 here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html