# Spring JPA: How can I see the commits being issued in the logs?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch app that processes 1000s of rows of data in batches of 20 (the `throttle-limit` per thread). The `commit-interval` in the batch configuration is also 20. Data that has been processed is kept in a detail table reflecting its status (in a Postgresql database).

I'm finding that the more data I throw at the app, the last few batches don't get committed to the detail table, although the processes in the batch were executed successfully. So right now I'm combing through logs to see where the commits are occurring, but can't seem to come up with the right logger. In my properties file I have `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace`, and here are my loggers:

```
  <logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.hibernatec" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>
```

And here's the method that issues the statements that aren't always being committed:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Override
public void updateJobDetail(String jobId, String domainCode, String codesDelimited, Date effectiveDate,
                                   StatusEnum status, String userId) {

        [business logic]

        detailRepository.save(entities);
        detailRepository.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
}
```

I guess my question is two-fold: Why might the database not reflect the last few batches, and how do I see in the logs if commits are being issued?

Update: Here is what the logs do show. Why are the statements being logged twice, I wonder?

```
15:35:02.288 [ThreadPoolExecutor-26] INFO  c.e.s.i.DetailServiceImpl - updateDetail - exit in 101 ms
15:35:02.288 [ThreadPoolExecutor-26] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [com.erd.service.impl.DetailServiceImpl.updateDetail]
15:35:02.288 [ThreadPoolExecutor-26] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [com.erd.service.impl.DetailServiceImpl.updateDetail]
```

Comment: Where is this `updateJobDetail` called? Is it called in the scope of the transaction driven by Spring Batch (in a processor or writer for example) ?

Comment: Yes, it's called within the Writer. Do you need to see that?

Comment: Your writer will be called in the scope of a transaction driven by Spring Batch. You need to remove `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155661/5019386.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot catch exception in spring batch's ItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146209/cannot-catch-exception-in-spring-batchs-itemwriter)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks so much, but I don't understand. I use `REQUIRES_NEW` because I need to see the results immediately in the db, otherwise we can't see the detail result until the entire batch is finished. And this works for smaller batches as intended. It's only the larger batches where I'm not seeing the detail table updated. Why would it work sometimes and not others?

Comment: I can't answer this question without reproducing the issue and debugging it. `I use REQUIRES_NEW because I need to see the results immediately in the db`: I added an answer regarding that as well as your initial question in the title with more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I use REQUIRES_NEW because I need to see the results immediately in the db, otherwise we can't see the detail result until the entire batch is finished.

I see no valid reason for that. Why use a chunk oriented step in the first place then? A chunk oriented step is used when a chunk of records is meant to be processed and written **as a unit** (at the chunk' transaction boundaries), aka all or nothing semantics.

So trying to work around that with nested smaller transactions inside the one driven by Spring Batch is working against the goal of chunk-oriented processing in the first place.

I recommend changing your approach by removing `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` and choosing a smaller chunk size if you want to see more records committed more frequently to the database.

> How can I see the commits being issued in the logs?

In addition to setting the log level to debug for Spring Batch and Spring JDBC, I use [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) to see all statements sent to the database. It will give you something like:

```
1543399291411|0|statement|connection0|select BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ.nextval from dual
1543399291412|0|statement|connection0|INSERT into BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID, VERSION, STEP_NAME, JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED) values(1, 0, 'step', 1, '28-Nov-18', NULL, 'STARTING', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'EXECUTING', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '28-Nov-18')
1543399291413|0|statement|connection0|INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, STEP_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES('{}', NULL, 1)
1543399291413|0|commit|connection0|
```